# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Clinic\fusioncharts.php on line 26

Tags: php, arrays

**Hey guys! Can someone execute a proper syntax for this type of code? Thanks!
This is the line 26 by the way :)**

```
$result = $dbhandle-$query($strQuery) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle-errno}): {$dbhandle-error}");
```

Comment: Did you HTML entity the code for SO, or is this your real code?

Comment: This isn't my code. This is an example which I was trying to copy to mine and I was wondering what is wrong with it.

Comment: `$dbhandle-$query($strQuery)` needs to be `$dbhandle->$query($strQuery)` and same for others. `$dbhandle->errno` and `$dbhandle->err`

Comment: I tried it mate, only now, it shows me I have unexpected '{'

Comment: this is proper syntax:  $result = $dbhandle->query($strQuery) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");